# Docker image fails building in Github Action "Module not found: Can't resolve './Nav/Navbar'

Tags: typescript, docker, kubernetes, next.js, github-actions

I have my applications and containers building and working locally, but the Github Action always fails with the below logs while I'm trying to launch this to a k8s cluster. I've tried modifying the names of the "Nav" directory with different case-sensitive matching, but to no avail. It seems like this is a common problem but everything I've seen hasn't helped. The NextJS files are all there and I'm very worried about breaking my application locally in the process of trying to get it through the CI/CD pipeline.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated, I am perplexed as to why this is failing and at the last step no less. I am also on a Windows 11.

**The Github Action error**

```
#14 1.125 - info Creating an optimized production build...
#14 15.91 Failed to compile.
#14 15.91 
#14 15.91 ./app/layout.tsx
#14 15.91 Module not found: Can't resolve './Nav/Navbar'
#14 15.91 
#14 15.91 https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
#14 15.91 
#14 15.91 
#14 15.91 > Build failed because of webpack errors
#14 15.95 npm notice 
#14 15.95 npm notice New minor version of npm available! 10.2.4 -> 10.5.0
#14 15.95 npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v10.5.0>
#14 15.95 npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@10.5.0` to update!
#14 15.95 npm notice 
#14 ERROR: process "/bin/sh -c npm run build" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
------
 > [builder 5/5] RUN npm run build:
15.91 
15.91 https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
15.91 
15.91 
15.91 > Build failed because of webpack errors
15.95 npm notice 
15.95 npm notice New minor version of npm available! 10.2.4 -> 10.5.0
15.95 npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v10.5.0>
15.95 npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@10.5.0` to update!
15.95 npm notice 
------
frontend/web-app/Dockerfile:15
--------------------
  13 |     ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1
  14 |     
  15 | >>> RUN npm run build
  16 |     
  17 |     # production image, copy all files and run next
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c npm run build" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
Error: buildx failed with: ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c npm run build" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

**Dockerfile for NextJS app**

```
FROM node:18-alpine AS deps
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app

COPY frontend/web-app/package*.json ./
RUN  npm install --omit-dev

FROM node:18-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY frontend/web-app ./

ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN npm run build

# production image, copy all files and run next
FROM node:18-alpine AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV production

ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs

COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public
COPY --from=builder /app/package.json ./package.json
COPY --from=builder /app/next.config.js ./next.config.js

COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static

USER nextjs

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT 3000

CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

**Github Action**

```
name: deploy-webapp

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  push:
    branches: [ "master" ]
    paths:
      - 'frontend/web-app/**'

env:
  REGISTRY_IMAGE: amg31/web-app
  DOCKERFILE: frontend/web-app/Dockerfile
  DEPLOYMENT_NAME: webapp

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v2
      - name: Login to DockerHub
        uses: docker/login-action@v2
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_PASSWORD }}
      - name: Build and push the Docker image
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v3
        with:
          context: "{{defaultContext}}"
          file: ${{ env.DOCKERFILE }}
          push: true
          tags: ${{ env.REGISTRY_IMAGE }}:latest
      - name: Install doctl
        uses: digitalocean/action-doctl@v2
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.DIGITALOCEAN_ACCESS_TOKEN }}
      - name: Save DigitalOcean kubeconfig
        run: doctl kubernetes cluster kubeconfig save auctionnext
      - name: Restart Kubernetes deployment
        run: kubectl rollout restart deployment ${{ env.DEPLOYMENT_NAME }}
```

**Layout.tsx file**

```
import React from 'react'
import {getCurrentUser} from './actions/authActions'
import './globals.css'
import Navbar from './Nav/Navbar'
import SignalRProvider from './providers/SignalRProvider'
import ToasterProvider from './providers/ToasterProvider'

export const metadata = {
    title: 'AuctionNext',
    description: 'Generated by create next app',
}

export default async function RootLayout({
                                             children,
                                         }: {
    children: React.ReactNode
}) {
    const user = await getCurrentUser();
    return (
        <html lang="en">
        <body>
        <ToasterProvider/>
        <Navbar/>
        <main className='container mx-auto px-5 pt-10'>
            <SignalRProvider user={user}>
                {children}
            </SignalRProvider>

        </main>

        </body>
        </html>
    )
}
```

Comment: I think the issue is the location of `Nav` folder from `lyaout.tsx`.

`./` means to start from the current folder.
`../` means to go up one folder and start from there.

Comment: I tried that, sadly got "./app/layout.tsx
#14 16.54 Module not found: Can't resolve '../Nav/Navbar'"